# How to install React on WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, installation, webstorm

I'm having trouble installing React on an empty project in WebStorm. The instructions on the [WebStorm help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html) tells me to get `create-react-app`.

Is there a way I can just get react? And if not, what is the difference between the two?

I'm trying to follow [this specific tutorial series online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AbaV3nrw6E&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBuKtLgPR_zWYnrwv-JllpA&index=1) about React for beginners. It's a 4 minute video so can anyone please explain to me what the youtuber did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using create-react-app because you will not need to install or configure tools like Webpack or Babel.

You need to install it from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app if you have npm (node package manager) installed you can just type `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: Can i use jsx with creat-react-app??

Comment: Yes you can use it with create-react-app.